# Blitting zoomed images using SDL

Tags: c++, c, sdl

Is there any way to Blit a zoomed (in) version of a certain image/sprite using SDL? (Besides manually saving a zoomed version of the image..)

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not with the SDL API itself.

I think there exist libraries (for SDL) who support zooming (so called resizing).

EDIT: http://www.ferzkopp.net/joomla/content/view/19/14/

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, SDL isn't suitable for graphics that require real-time rotations and zooming. For that, you'd need an library based around an accelerated API such as DirectX or OpenGL. I understand that [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/) meets this requirement.